# How to quickly search and navigate to the particular sub directory?

Tags: bash, zsh, cd-command

I often find myself in the situation where the directory structure is like:

`a/b/c/d/f/g/...`

and I am at `a` as `pwd` and wish to quickly navigate to `f` or `g`.

Is it possible to search and move to the particular directory from `a` as my `pwd`?

Comment: In bash or in zsh?

Comment: preferably in `zsh`.

Comment: In `zsh` fastest is to use double star glob: `cd **/g` (assuming there is only one subdirectory `g`). In `bash` you need to `shopt -s globstar` first.

Comment: @jimmij Wow!! Just what I wanted! Thanks a lot. If it was added as and answer I would have accepted an uprooted it!  Can you explain the meaning of `**/` ? :)

Comment: @jimmij any website where I can learn more such cool tricks in zsh?

Comment: How about http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/zsh ? :)